# Getting clean mail data from Microsft Graph API

Tags: python, django, get, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to get clean mail data from Microsoft Graph API into a Django template.

I have tried using

```
headers={'Prefer': 'outlook.body-content-type="text"'}
```

and

```
headers={'Prefer': 'outlook.body-content-type="html"'}
```

in my python `GET` request but both of them result in data with tags in them. I have tried using regex to clean my data but it is not as effective because regex removes some important texts.

Is there a simpler way of getting a cleaner mail data?

Comment: Yes you need to use the body property of the message to get whether its HTML/Text. You can use preference headers to get it. When you specify either header, a successful response would include the corresponding Preference-Applied header,
(1) For text format requests: Preference-Applied: outlook.body-content-type="text"
(2) For HTML format requests: Preference-Applied: outlook.body-content-type="html"
If the body is HTML, by default, Outlook removes any potentially unsafe HTML (for example, JavaScript) embedded in the body property before returning the body content in a REST response.

Comment: To get the entire, original HTML content, include the "Prefer: outlook.allow-unsafe-html
" HTTP request header

Comment: This is the closest ones you can try, apart from that you can $value of the message to get the MIME as final option.

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up retrieving HTML data then cleaned out the tags using Beautiful Soup. I believe getting MIME would work but I am satisfied with the effectiveness of Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Glad that it helped you moving forward.

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider [accepting the answer and upvoting it](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). So it can be useful to others in the community as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the body property of the message to get whether its HTML/Text. You can use preference headers to get it. When you specify either header, a successful response would include the corresponding Preference-Applied header,

- For text format requests: Preference-Applied:
  outlook.body-content-type="text"
- For HTML format requests:
  Preference-Applied: outlook.body-content-type="html"

If the body is
HTML, by default, Outlook removes any potentially unsafe HTML (for
example, JavaScript) embedded in the body property before returning
the body content in a REST response.

- To get the entire, original HTML content, include the "Prefer: outlook.allow-unsafe-html " HTTP request header
- Apart from the above, you can $value of the message to get the MIME too.
- In addition,  you ended up retrieving HTML data then cleaned out the tags using Beautiful Soup.